# systemd memory limit user instance not working

Tags: systemd, cgroups

I'm using Arch Linux and systemd version is 239. I booted system with systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=1 kernel parameter.

I made two unit files, limit.slice and malloc.service.

limit.slice is

```
[Unit]
Description=limit memory slice.

[Slice]
MemoryAccounting=yes
MemoryMax=100M
```

and malloc.service is

```
[Unit]
Description=memory consuming process

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/example/malloc_program
Slice=limit.slice
```

malloc_program is just keep calls malloc() to consume memory.

I put these files to /home/example/.config/systemd/user/ and run `systemctl --user start malloc.service`.
Service's CGroup is under `limit.slice` as expected.

```
CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/limit.slice/malloc.service
```

But, the process keeps running even when the used memory was over 100 MB.

I can't understand why memory limitation is not working in user instance...

Comment: "malloc_program is just keep calls malloc() to consume memory" -> That's usually not enough, you usually need to "touch" the pages for Linux to actually allocate them for you. If you want a system to test using memory, consider using `memhog` which is typically shipped with the "numactl" package.

Comment: Actually, I implemented that too. Sorry for lack of explenation.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set for malloc service at .slice file:

```
[Slice]
MemoryAccounting=true
MemoryLimit=100M
MemoryMax=100M
MemoryHigh=50M
```

Comment: It didn't work... Maybe it is a bug of systemd? https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/9512

Comment: For future reference: the bug was reported as a regression in systemd v239 (the bug does not seem present in v237), and the bug was closed by a fix that is applied to v240.